# Using Browser Control's PostUrlL API

Tags: webbrowser-control, symbian, http-post, panic

I'm trying to **POST** some **multipart form** data to my server using a *Browser Control.*

The `PostUrlL();` Method Panics with `KERN-EXEC 3` as soon as it is invoked.

Here's a snippet similar to the one I'm using in my code.

```
// These LITerals are copied to pointer vars below
_LIT8(K_txt_Boundary, "0xABeR1122EEFFx0");
_LIT8(K_CT_MultipartFormData,"multipart/form-data");

HBufC *url = HBufC::NewL(URL_SIZE);
HBufC8 *contentType = HBufC::NewL(CONTENT_TYPE_SIZE);
HBufC8 *bufPostData = HBufC::NewL(POST_DATA_SIZE);
HBufC8 *boundary = HBufC::NewL(BOUNDARY_SIZE);

// Check allocation was successful 
// and copy required data to allocated space.

TAny *any = NULL;

TRAPD(error, iBrowser->PostUrlL(
                       *url, 
                       *contentType, 
                       *bufPostData, 
                       boundary, 
                       any)
             );
```

**`iBrowser`, the browser control handle is created as follows:**
*I'm ommiting error checking, but I do TRAP the function call within which the following snippet is placed.*

```
iBrowserCapabilties = TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityDisplayScrollBar 
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityLoadHttpFw 
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityGraphicalHistory 
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityGraphicalPage 
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityClientResolveEmbeddedURL 
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityCursorNavigation
                                | TBrCtlDefs::ECapabilityClientNotifyURL;

iBrowserObserver = CBrowserObserver::NewL(this);

iBrowser = CreateBrowserControlL(   
                iAppView, 
                aRect,
                iBrowserCapabilties,
                TBrCtlDefs::ECommandIdBase, 
                NULL, // Soft keys
                iBrowserObserver, // Link Resolver
                NULL,
                NULL // Layout change 
        );

iBrowser->SetBrowserSettingL(TBrCtlDefs::ESettingsCookiesEnabled, ETrue);
```

I've cross checked to see if any of the pointer vars are NULL by logging their contents, they all seem to be fine, except for the **any** pointer which is intentional. (The document says it's reserved for future use, so I believe NULL should be an appropriate value).

I've also verified that `iBrowser` is a valid instance of a browser control. *As mentiond above, I'm* `TRAP`ing *the function which contains the code to create the browser control*

The call `PostUrlL();` fails with panic `KERN-EXEC 3`.

Any pointers, suggestions or alternatives are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that iBrowser points to a valid object?

Comment: @chalup: Yes, it points to a valid object. I've used iBrowser to already load a URL. Thanks for replying.

Comment: What are the params you're passing to `CreateBrowserControlL()`?

Comment: I've update the question to include more details as asked by all of you. Thanks again for showing interest.

Comment: At first I was thinking of parameter lifetime issues - the HBufCs seem to go out of scope before the request is fully processed but then I checked the browsercontrol source (http://developer.symbian.org/xref/oss/xref/Symbian3/sf/mw/web/webengine/osswebengine/WebKit/s60/webview/BrCtl.cpp) and noticed it takes copies of all parameters passed in. I'll check more into this tomorrow when I get on a box with Symbian environments.

Comment: @laato: Not an issue :) Thanks for your interest. Hope I can get this working on time. Meanwhile I'm implementing an alternative.

Comment: Now I tried to reproduce this on N97 SDK. I copy pasted your code, added some necessary glue code here and there and it worked just fine. The browser engine will in turn invoke e.g. `ResolveLinkL()` in your `CBrowserObserver` - make sure the problem is not in there.

Comment: @laalto: Hmm, I'm going through symbian OS's code, and it looks pretty fine. Could this be an issue with my phone model? I'm testing on Nokia E63. Also I'm using the Symbian^3 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question comments:

> I'm testing on Nokia E63. Also I'm using the Symbian^3 SDK.

E63 is a S60 3rd Edition Feature Pack 1 (S60 3.1) device. Though much attention has been given to binary compability between platform version, you should really be using a S60 3rd Edition SDK such as 3.0 or 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I would soon be downloading the S60 3rd Edition SDK and testing my code.

Comment: In S60 3rd Edition SDK, Browser Control does not contain the PostUrlL() method :( . I've cross checked with S60 3.x source code. Thanks for your time. I'm awarding the answer to you, and yeah +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

could u verfiied the input parameter for PostUrl method here [Platform Browser Control API documentation](http://www.forum.nokia.com/document/Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/Platform_Browser_Control_API4.html)  ???
and verify that u browser control is member on the class and initialized.